# how to add the layout dialect to spring-boot thymeleaf autoconfiguration file

Tags: maven, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Good day, I have just created a project to use Spring-boot, and thymeleaf. I am attempting to take advantage of the layout dialect in order to take advantage of its "tiles like templating". I have looked up this problem and each response recommends me to add the layout dialect as a spring-boot configuration file. but each attempt I have had at this has failed, the most recent one came from this link [How do I add a thymeleaf dialect to spring boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23531580/how-do-i-add-a-thymeleaf-dialect-to-spring-boot) . so I added this in the configuration file

```
@Configuration
public class ThymleafConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public LayoutDialect layoutDialect() {
        return new LayoutDialect();
    }
}
```

but it always results with:

```
"Error resolving template "layout.html", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers (welcomeHome:4)"
```

however the layout.html is in the /resources/templates folder, so i know it isnt a location mismatch. My goal is just to add the layout Dialect with out disrupting too much of the spring-boot autoconfiguration settings. my pom has both the thymeleaf-layout-dialect and thymeleaf starter dependencies.

welcomeHome.html

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
      layout:decorator="layout.html">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
```

stack trace:

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "layout.html", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers (welcomeHome:4)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateRepository.getTemplate(TemplateRepository.java:245)
    at nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf.decorator.DecoratorProcessor.processAttribute(DecoratorProcessor.java:92)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.attr.AbstractAttrProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttrProcessor.java:87)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.AbstractProcessor.process(AbstractProcessor.java:212)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.applyNextProcessor(Node.java:1016)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:971)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:672)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:655)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Document.process(Document.java:93)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1155)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1060)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1011)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:335)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1221)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1005)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:952)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1736)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1695)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.worksBeyond</groupId>
    <artifactId>worksBeyondv2</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>WorksBeyond</name>
    <description>A base project for works beyond</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.9.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-social-facebook</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-social-linkedin</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-social-twitter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <start-class>worksBeyond.Application</start-class>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>neo4j</id>
            <name>Neo4j</name>
            <url>http://m2.neo4j.org/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

OK! so I figured out the solution. The issue lied within the decorator name in the view resolver. So in the welcomeHome.html the original decorator declaration was:

```html
welcomeHome.html
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
      layout:decorator="layout.html">
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
```

The working solution is :

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
  layout:decorator="layout">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
```

The difference lies in the omitting the ".html" at the end of layout.html . So

layout:decorator="layout.html"

becomes:

layout:decorator="layout"

From what I am now understanding, the thymeleafautoconfiguration sets the suffix to .html. which means it isnt necessary to add it in the decorator's file name.

Comment: Correct. Or you can change the suffix in "spring.thymeleaf.suffix".

Comment: right.And for anyone reading this that is using spring boot: you can change common default settings in the application.properties file that comes with your spring boot application. This is where you would go to override your thymeleaf suffix(the location of the view) and the prefix (the extension on the view ie: .html, .jsp, etc)

a list of common properties can be found here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

Answer (score 0):

The `LayoutDialect` is already autoconfigured, so you shouldn't need to do anything. Are you sure "templates/layout.html" is actually on the classpath?

Comment: And that is what I thought as well Dave. My only assurance of it being on the classpath is that when I load it without the layout decorator, the thymeleaf resolves the view correctly.

The fact spring-boot is supposed to autoconfigure the bean once its in my Pom.xml makes this a bit more troublesome.